# pg_dump - permission denied (db:structure:dump)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have problems with getting db:structure:dump to work.

I and getting this error:

```
C:\Sites\care>rake db:structure:dump --trace
Creating scope :search. Overwriting existing method PgSearch::Document.search.
** Invoke db:structure:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:structure:dump
rake aborted!
Permission denied - pg_dump -i -s -x -O -f C:/Sites/care/db/structure.sql  care_development
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:389:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
```

If I run it like this in CMD, it works:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin
pg_dump.exe -i -s -x -O -f C:/Sites/care/db/structure.sql care_development
```

I have tried changing the permission on both the pg_dump.exe folder/file and the rails folder/files. But doesn't seem to make any different. Tried adding full permissions for Users, System and even Everyone.

I also tried adding --username params to the pg_dump call (in the rake code) and adding Login Roles that match my windows user in pgAdminIII.

(I'm on Windows 7, Rails 3 and postgreSQL 9)

Do anyone know what the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on my Linux machine:
Then i used the following command to make it run:

```
su

>> I logged in first with my Admin user 

su -postgres
```

I save my .sql file in my `/tmp` folder

For dumping the `.sql` file in database i run the command

```
psql -u postgres -d my_db_name -a -f /tmp/path_to_sql_file
```

It works greatly for me. Hope it may help you.

Comment: Also you can put your 'structure.sql' in your temporary folder of windows.